# Running a macro via task scheduler in Windows server 2012

Tags: vba, object, ms-access, outlook, scheduler

We have created a macro to run in MS access (Office 365) on windows server 2012 so that it runs script that creates and sends emails via MS outlook. We can run the macro from inside MS Access but we cannot get windows task scheduler to automatically schedule this process. What we are doing is creating invoices for our customers automatically using MS Access. The macro works perfectly if we execute it within the open file. It creates all the emails with an invoice attached as a PDF which is then sent via outlook to our customers. This is all done with one click of the macro. But we cannot get this process to schedule via windows task scheduler. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your Outlook also running? if yes then use Outlook reminder to call the macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as the comments don't allow enough info to be posted.

We have finally managed to do this using the suggestion in one of the above comments to use Outlook reminders rather than task scheduler.

This solution involves setting up a task and scheduled reminder in OUTLOOK. 
The recurrent schedule for the reminder in Outlook acts as a replacement for Task Scheduler. 
We categorised the reminder to aid the exact identification. (For task add new category and give it a name)
The VBA script in Outlook is triggered by identifying the reminder category and the MSAccess macro is initiated which sends the emails then closes the Access application. This is done on a set scheduled recurrent basis as set for this Outlook reminder task.
The only  issue we had was with the following line
    mydb.Application.Run "MacroName" 
the resulting error was rectified by
mydb.DoCmd.RunMacro “MacroName”

We now have a method of scheduling which works.

It would seem that when an Access VBA script, which includes sending an email is  called from an OUTLOOK scheduled script it has no problem in completing the task, whereas, the exact same script actioned through Task Scheduler just does not complete.

Hope this helps others.